# Is it possible to change a printer's PID/descriptor to allow compatibility with a different model name?

Tags: windows, printing, driver, descriptor

Short Description: I need to spoof a printer PID/descriptor so that when I plug this printer into a device that is running on a windows OS, it will see that printer as the one it has the drivers for. I am able to change the hardware on the printer but I am unable to change or install drivers on this windows OS device as the system is locked.

Long Description: I have a printer that was purchased with a system, the company who sold that system got bought out and released a new system, we purchased the new system hoping that we could use the old printer from the previous system, but the company that sells the new system has taken the exact same printer but changed the model name, the manual and operation of the printer is the exact same, but with a different Product identification number/descriptor and when I plug in the old printer to the new system it is not recognized as the windows os does not have the drivers for the old printer. I am looking for a way to spoof the PID/descriptor so this old printer is recognized as the same model as the new printer.

I am not sure if this is the right forum to post this in though.

I have already tried accessing the windows os on the device and the security of the unit prevents me from installing any new drivers on the device, I have access to all the boards in the printer but I am not sure if PID/descriptors is something you can change on a board as this is not my area of expertise. I was thinking of buying a raspberry pi as a go between connecting the printer and the windows os device but I would like to find out if it is possible first before making any purchases.